# Datatables::of()->make(true); returns an error Call to a member function getQuery() on array

Tags: datatables, laravel-5, yajra-datatable

Good day. I want to display my data in a data tables but I encountered and error Call to a member function getQuery() on array.

Iámnew to laravel and this yajra library. hope someone can help me fix this error.

here is my ajax. It will pass level_id and level to my controller then return the result of the query if match.

```
//GENERAL
var $i=0;
var level_id = '{{ @$level->id }}';
var level = '{{ @$_level }}';

var viewStudent
function view_students($this){
    viewStudent
    if ($('#viewStudent-div').is(':hidden')) {
        $(".sidebar .menus").removeClass("active");
        $($this).addClass("active");

        $('#viewStudent-div').siblings().hide('slow/400/fast', function() {
            $('#viewStudent-div').show('slow/400/fast');
        });
    }
}

$(function(){
    viewStudent = $('#viewStudent-table').DataTable({
        order: [[ 0, "asc" ]],
        Language: {
            sLoadingRecords:"<img src='{{asset('assets/images/load.gif')}}' style='max-height:30px;'/> Fetching data...",
            sEmptyTable: "No data available"
        },
        ajax:{
            url:'{{ route("json_product_user") }}',
            data: function (d) {
                d.level_id = level_id;
                d.level = level;
            }
        },
        columnDefs: [
            {
                targets: 0,
                searchable:false,
                orderable:false,
            },
        ],
        columns:[
            {
                data: "full_name",
                render: function(data, type, row){
                    return data;
                }
            },
            {
                data: "product_name",
                render: function(data, type, row){
                    var html = '';
                    html += '<p style="">'+data+'</p>';
                    return html;
                }
            },
            {
                data: "level",
                render: function(data, type, row){
                    return data;
                }
            },
            {
                data: "date_purchase",
                render: function(data, type, row){
                var html = '';
                html += '<p style="text-align: center">'+moment(data).format('MMM-DD-YYYY')+'</p>';
                    return html;
                }
            }
        ]
    });
});
```

and this is my controller

```
public function viewStudents(Request $request)
{
    if( $request->has('level_id') ){
        if($request->level == 'school') {
            $query = DB::table('product_user')
                ->leftJoin('products', 'product_user.product_id', '=', 'products.id')
                ->leftJoin('school_products', 'product_user.product_id', '=', 'school_products.product_id')
                ->leftJoin('users', 'product_user.user_id', '=', 'users.id')
                ->whereRaw("school_products.school_id = " . $request->level_id . " OR products.organization_id = ".$org_id)
                ->select('products.name as product_name', DB::raw('CONCAT(users.last_name, ", ", users.first_name ) AS  full_name'), 'product_user.created_at', 'products.level as level')
                ->get();
        }
        else{
            $query= DB::table('product_user')
                ->leftJoin('products', 'product_user.product_id', '=', 'products.id')
                ->leftJoin('school_products', 'product_user.product_id', '=', 'school_products.product_id')
                ->leftJoin('users', 'product_user.user_id', '=', 'users.id')
                ->whereRaw("products.level = 'organization' AND products.organization_id = ".$request->level_id)
                ->select('products.name as product_name', DB::raw('CONCAT(users.last_name, ", ", users.first_name ) AS  full_name'), 'product_user.created_at', 'products.level as level')
                ->get();

        }
    }
     //        return $query;
    return  Datatables::of($query)->make(true);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I believe since you are using DB, the return type of DB select is an array of plain objects (stdClass). In this case you have to convert the output to \Illuminate\Support\Collection, either by using

```
$collection = new \Illuminate\Support\Collection($query);
return  Datatables::of($collection)->make(true);
```

or

```
$collection = collect($query);
return Datatables::of($collection)->make(true);
```

collect() works for me in laravel 5.3. Please take a look at this answer:
https://github.com/laravel/docs/issues/2867#issuecomment-343664438